# gnuplot-iostream not linking to boost

Tags: c++, gnuplot

Hi I'm trying to use gnuplot-iostream, at the minute I'm just trying to get the code [here](http://www.stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/) working. When I try to combile I get errors in the linker saying:

```
In function `stream<int, boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_flags>':
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/stream.hpp:130: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink::file_descriptor_sink(int, boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_flags)'

In function `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink boost::iostreams::detail::wrap<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink>(boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink const&, boost::disable_if<boost::iostreams::is_std_io<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink>, void>::type*)':
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/detail/wrap_unwrap.hpp:53: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink::file_descriptor_sink(boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink const&)'

In function `concept_adapter':
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/detail/adapter/concept_adapter.hpp:67: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink::file_descriptor_sink(boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink const&)'
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/detail/adapter/concept_adapter.hpp:38: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink::file_descriptor_sink(boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink const&)'

In function `long boost::iostreams::detail::write_device_impl<boost::iostreams::output>::write<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink>(boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink&, boost::iostreams::char_type_of<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink>::type const*, long)':
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/write.hpp:121: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor::write(char const*, long)'

In function `void boost::iostreams::detail::close_impl<boost::iostreams::closable_tag>::close<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink>(boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink&, std::_Ios_Openmode)':
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/close.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor::close()'

In function `std::fpos<__mbstate_t> boost::iostreams::detail::seek_device_impl<boost::iostreams::any_tag>::seek<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink>(boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink&, long, std::_Ios_Seekdir, std::_Ios_Openmode)':
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/seek.hpp:137: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor::seek(long, std::_Ios_Seekdir)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note I have boost installed and have previously compiled programs that use iostream.
Any help massively appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruling out the obvious... are you compiling with `g++ -lboost_iostreams`? If you can share some information about how the compiler and linker are being invoked it will make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm building in eclipse. When I look at settings for gcc c++ compiler, it say command g++ then in the all options box -I/usr/include/boost -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0. Binary Parser is Elf, error Parsers CDT, tool chain is Linux GCC, current builder is GNU make Builder. If you need more information please ask, preferably let me know where to find it. Sorry if some of the stuff is superfluous. I like programming but haven't the foggiest when it comes to building/compiling.

Comment: I'm not familiar with eclipse, but I do know that `-I/usr/include/boost` only tells the compiler where to find the boost headers. It does not tell the linker where to find the boost libraries. See if there's a way to make eclipse add `-lboost_iostreams` to the list of compiler arguments.

Comment: Brilliant, solved by adding boost_iostream to properties->c/C++ Build->Settings->GCC C++ Linker->Libraries(-l).

Answer (score 0):

Run into exact problem when tried to use g++ with gnuplot-iostream library.

```
g++ prog.cpp -L/usr/lib -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_iostreams
```

Resolved the issue for me - the code were compiled successfully with no errors.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as above but I build under vs community and using cmake lists adding these lines here https://github.com/dstahlke/gnuplot-iostream/issues/8 did not solve my issue. Any Idea how I can achieve linking to lboost_filesystem etc. as you wrote it in cmake lists??