# Linking error with boost process (and other boost libs)

Tags: c++, boost, linker

Here's my code. I'm just testing Boost::process so I'll be able to use it if/when I need to. I don't know why I'm getting the linking error that I am getting. I'm a rather novice C++ programmer. I know the concepts, but I make frequent errors in practice and am bad at debugging. I appreciate any help I can get with this.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/process.hpp>
#include<boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp>

namespace bp = ::boost::process;
namespace bpi = ::boost::process::initializers;
namespace bio = ::boost::iostreams;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  bp::pipe p = bp::create_pipe();
  bio::file_descriptor_sink sink(p.sink, bio::close_handle);

  bp::execute(
          bpi::run_exe("/usr/bin/ls"),
          bpi::bind_stdout(sink)
          );
  return(0);
}
```

And here is my error…

```
/tmp/cc7cmrV8.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink::file_descriptor_sink(int, boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_flags)'
/tmp/cc7cmrV8.o: In function `boost::process::posix::initializers::bind_stdout::bind_stdout(boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink const&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7process5posix12initializers11bind_stdoutC2ERKNS_9iostreams20file_descriptor_sinkE[_ZN5boost7process5posix12initializers11bind_stdoutC5ERKNS_9iostreams20file_descriptor_sinkE]+0x2b): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink::file_descriptor_sink(boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink const&)'
/tmp/cc7cmrV8.o: In function `void boost::process::posix::initializers::bind_stdout::on_exec_setup<boost::process::posix::executor>(boost::process::posix::executor&) const':
test.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost7process5posix12initializers11bind_stdout13on_exec_setupINS1_8executorEEEvRT_[_ZNK5boost7process5posix12initializers11bind_stdout13on_exec_setupINS1_8executorEEEvRT_]+0x18): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor::handle() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Platform: Linux 64-bit
Boost: 1.55 (installed via pacman)
Boost::process: 0.5
Compile command: `g++ -Wall test.cpp -o spegh.elf -lboost_system`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple search threw me at [-This-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075810/gnuplot-iostream-not-linking-to-boost).

Seeing you posted your compile command, I'm guessing you are simply missing `-lboost_iostreams` in your linker settings.

Comment: Oh my apologies. I searched but did not find anything. I will try that when I get back home. Pardon my noob question, but that thread you linked indicates that that linker option would be obvious. It was not obvious to me. Where do I look to see what linker options are needed for future reference?

Comment: @smalltock Because something looks obvious for some, doesn't mean it is obvious for everyone, so don't worry about 'newbie' questions. I'm no Boost expert, but the first place I would look is the documentation/manual. [-Here-](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/) is the documentation for boost libs. That page lists every lib there is and I'm guessing that each of those should be linked (when used) with `-lboost_<lib-name-here>`, but I could be wrong. Perhaps the [-Boost Getting started-](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/) page might give some extra info. =]